# Second OS disappeared from grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm dual-booting Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 7. Ubuntu was installed first but now CentOS is my daily driver.

After updating Ubuntu, I can no longer access my CentOS install. When I boot my computer it loads Ubuntu's grub menu which doesn't list CentOS.

I've tried running `update-grub` but the command only finds Ubuntu. I've also tried to solve the problem by running `boot-repair` from a Live CD: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14590076/

If I understand the output from `boot-repair` correctly, a complication is that the Centos install (on `/dev/sda4`) is encrypted.

I think a solution might be to delete Ubuntu's grub (installed in the MBR of `/dev/sda`). However, I fear that might leave my computer completely unbootable.

I'd be quite happy with a solution involving deleting the Ubuntu install altogether. My aim is really to be able to boot into CentOS again.

Comment: @spacelander - yes, os-prober is already installed.

Comment: Nice first question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @TrevG123 got me close enough to solve the problem. I booted a Centos 7 live DVD; selected to rescue an existing system and then ran `grub2-install --root-directory=/mnt/sysimage/ /dev/sda` at the prompt. After rebooting the computer I got the Centos grub menu (which also listed Ubuntu).

Comment: Glad you got it!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a CentOS live CD you could try installing Grub from that since sometimes Ubuntu can have issues reading the file systems used by Redhat distros, while Cent can usually read ext4

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx

sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Manual entry to the grub2. There were many posts to do it.
But it was quite difficult to add an entry to the grub-2. (As far as i Known, Because almost everything is changed compared to grub, Too many options)